# Does XMLEventReader/XMLStreamReader throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, xml-parsing

If there is any illegal argument corresponding an attribute (say date) inside the tags in the xml string passed to XMLEventReader/XMLStreamReader, then does XMLEventReader/XMLStreamReader throws a IllegalArgumentException or just sets the date attribute to null ?

If it doesn't throw any exception,in that case is there any way to make it throw a desired exception in case of IllegalArgument passed for any attribute ?

Comment: The only method that thrws `IllegalArgumentException` in the `XMLEventReader` is `getProperty` and for `XMLStreamReader` there are two `getProperty` and `getNamespaceURI`

Comment: have you coded something, and can you put some trace and context ?